# MySQL integer quotation marks?

Tags: mysql, sql, int

When posting integer values into a MySQL database should I be using quotation marks?
what is the difference between using quotation marks and not using quotation marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a general programming answer in this case IMO. If you want to use integers, then you should not treat them like strings (use quotation marks). In most cases, you are forcing the processing engine to cast it from a string to an int. So, why add the extra work if it is already an int to begin with.

Comment: It can be useful in preventing SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you won't notice any difference, but the difference might be significant when you pass a lot of numerical ids to `IN` operator. The operator sorts its arguments to make random access more sequential, and string arguments might confuse the optimizer.